# Failing gsub in for loops

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I need to remove a series of substrings from a vector, that might or might not occur multiple times. The substrings to drop are less than the number of strings.

I would like to use a loop but gsub seems to fail in a for loop.

```
drop <- c("red ","blue ","yellow ")
auto <- data.frame(entry=c("red car","red yellow car","car"))

for(i in 1:length(drop)){
  auto$entry_simple <- gsub(drop[i],"",auto$entry)
}
```

The loops works only for the last entry how?
This is the result

```
           entry entry_simple
1        red car      red car
2 red yellow car      red car
3            car          car
```

Instead of

```
           entry entry_simple
1        red car          car
2 red yellow car          car
3            car          car
```

Comment: Does the solution works for you?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_remove` which is vectorized

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
auto %>% 
   mutate(entry_simple = str_remove(entry, drop))
#       entry entry_simple
#1    red car          car
#2   blue car          car
#3 yellow car          car
```

---

If we look at the loop, the `gsub` is done on the entire column 'entry' and the output is assigned to 'entry_simple' i.e. in each iteration, the 'entry_simple' is gettting changed

```
lapply(drop, function(x) gsub(x, "", auto$entry))
#[[1]]
#[1] "car"        "blue car"   "yellow car"

#[[2]]
#[1] "red car"    "car"        "yellow car"

#[[3]]
#[1] "red car"  "blue car" "car"
```

leaving the last one i.e. 'red car' 'blue car', 'car' as the final output

It seems the OP wanted to replace for each corresponding row.  In that case, just use the index on the 'x' value for `gsub` and on the lhs of `<-`

```
auto$entry_simple <- auto$entry
for(i in seq_along(drop)) auto$entry_simple[i] <- gsub(drop[i], "", auto$entry[i])
auto
#       entry entry_simple
#1    red car          car
#2   blue car          car
#3 yellow car          car
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's updated post

```
auto$entry_simple <- auto$entry
for(i in 1:length(drop)) auto$entry_simple <- gsub(drop[i],"",auto$entry_simple)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code breaks down with repeated entries.
e.g.
```
auto <- data.frame(entry=c("red car","red car","car"))
drop <- c("red ","blue ","yellow ")
```

To further calrify I am trying to substitute the loop for a (long) list of 

```auto$entry <- gsub("red ","",trimws(auto$entry))````

Comment: @MCS can you please update your post with a new  example.  The current example impies also that it is doing a replacement corresponding to each row, because the 'drop' length and number of rows of 'entry' are the same

Comment: Done.
I think it's resolved by simply using
for(i in seq_along(drop)) auto$entry <- gsub(drop[i], "",auto$entry)

Answer (score 0):

This works. Is it all down to "seq_along"?

```
for(i in seq_along(drop)) auto$entry <- gsub(drop[i], "",auto$entry)
```

Comment: No, it is not related to that.  The issue is that you are updating a different column whle the gusb is done on a different one.  Try `autor$entry_simple <- auto$entry` and then use the same update on both sides of the `<-`